# excel auto add row on sheet 2 everytime a range on sheet 1 added

Tags: vba, excel

sheet 1 is the current debt our clients have on us
and sheet 2 is the historical transaction of our company
is there a way so if everytime a row added in sheet 1 it will also be added on sheet 2
but everytime a row is removed from sheet 1, i doesn't on sheet 2
any idea?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target = Range("A1") Then
        If Range("A1").Value <> Range("A2").Value Then
            Range("C1").Value = Range("C1").Value + 1
            Range("A2").Value = Range("A1").Value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

i tried it as a start but it seems so not right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than linking the code to a `Worksheet_Change` action, I thought hooking it to a `Workbook_BeforeSave` would be a better stategy. In the below, the user is prompted to update the transaction sheet (`Sheet2` by your description) as soon as he or she saves the workbook. The logic revolves around copying all of the debts (from `Sheet1`) to the transaction sheet, then using Excel's built-in `Range.RemoveDuplicates` functionality:

[image: start1]
[image: start2]

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim Choice As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, _
    LastTransRow As Long, ColIndex As Long
Dim NewRange As Range, TargetRange As Range, _
    FullTransRange As Range
Dim DebtSheet As Worksheet, TransSheet As Worksheet
Dim HeaderArray() As Variant

'prompt user to update the transactions on sheet2
Choice = MsgBox("Would you like to update the transactions sheet before saving?", _
    vbYesNo, Title:="Update Transactions?")

If Choice = vbYes Then

    'set references up-front
    Set DebtSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set TransSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    With DebtSheet
        LastRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        LastCol = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    End With
    Set NewRange = Range(DebtSheet.Cells(2, 1), DebtSheet.Cells(LastRow, LastCol))

    'copy all the debt info to the bottom of the transactions data block
    With TransSheet
        LastTransRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        Set TargetRange = Range(.Cells(LastTransRow + 1, 1), .Cells(LastTransRow + LastRow - 1, LastCol))
    End With
    NewRange.Copy TargetRange

    'apply excel's dupe-removal to the full range
    With TransSheet
        Set FullTransRange = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastTransRow + LastRow - 1, LastCol))
    End With
    ReDim HeaderArray(0 To LastCol - 1)
    For ColIndex = 1 To LastCol
        HeaderArray(ColIndex - 1) = ColIndex
    Next ColIndex
    FullTransRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=HeaderArray, Header:=xlYes

End If

End Sub
```

[image: results]

Comment: Happy to help, this was an interesting problem to tackle!